# How do I use the UserManager from project A in project B?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2, hangfire

Both project A and project B are ASP NET Core 2.2 apps.

Project B uses Hangfire for background jobs and does very little else, and the fact that it uses Hangfire may not even be important (more on this at the bottom). Project A enqueues jobs on B's Hangfire.

Now, let's say I have my class representing a task, called Job. This is contained in project C, a plain old class library referenced by project B, and which in turns references other projects containing the entities it's working with.

Dependencies are to be injected into this class through the constructor:

```
public class Job
{
    public Job(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
               IThisRepository thisRepository,
               IThatRepository thatRepository)
    {
    }

    public void Execute(string userId)
    {
        // this is where the work gets done
    }
}
```

and for the most part they *do* get injected: `IThisRepository` and `IThatRepository` are injected and they work... mostly.

In project B's `Startup.cs`, the one that is supposed to run this job, I manually and successfully registered those interfaces, along with the `DbContext` that they require a some other stuff.

UserManager was quite a bit harder to register manually because of all the parameters its constructor requires, so since I didn't *really* need it inside my job, I just decided to make a few changes.

Now, an example of the entities I'm working with is as follows:

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // several other properties of primitive types

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}

public class Dish
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // several other properties of primitive types

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }        

    public Category Category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

now the problem is this: inside of Job I try to create a new Dish and associate it with both the user and the category. Since I just have the user id and I don't have access to `UserManager`, this is what I try to do:

```
// ...

var category = await categoryRepository.FindByUserAndCode(userId, "ABC");

// this is a category that is guaranteed to exist

var dish = new Dish();
dish.UserId = userId;
// notice there's no dish.User assignment, because I don't have an ApplicationUser object
dish.Category = category;

dishRepository.Upsert(dish); (which internally either creates a new entity or updates the existing one as appropriate)
```

and this is where it all breaks down, because it says that a category with the same Id I'm trying to insert is already present, so I'm trying to duplicate a primary key.

Since the category with code ABC for this user exists in the db, I thought it was odd.

Here's the thing: the instance of `Category` that the repository returns does have it's `UserId` property populated, but the `User` property is `null`.

I think this is what causes my problem: EF probably sees that the property is `null` and considers this object a new one.

I don't know why it comes up `null` (and it does even for other entities that all have a property referencing the user), but I tried to backtrack and, instead of using just the user id, I wanted to try to get Hangfire to instantiate `Job` injecting `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` into it, so at least I could get an instance of my user by its id.

It's worth noting that this works in other parts of project A, it's just that when I'm executing the background job something goes horribly wrong and I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

However the dependencies of `UserManager` are many, and I fear I might be barking up the wrong tree or doing it completely wrong.

I said that the fact I'm using Hangfire might not matter because the assumption under which it operates is: just give me the name of your class, I'll take care of instantiating it *as long as* all the dependencies have been registered.

Anyone has done this before and can help shed some light?

Answer (score 3):

You've included an absolute ton of information here that is *entirely* inconsequential to the problem at hand. What your issue boils down is simply the exception you're getting when attempting to add a dish: "a category with the same Id I'm trying to insert is already present, so I'm trying to duplicate a primary key."

This is most normally caused by attempting to use a detached entity as a relationship, i.e.:

```
dish.Category = category;
```

If `category` is detached from the context, then EF will attempt to create it because of this assignment, and since it already exists, that creation fails. We can't see what's going on in `categoryRepository.FindByUserAndCode`, but I'd imagine you're either calling `AsNoTracking` with the query, or are newing up an instance of `Category` manually yourself. In either case, that instance, then, is detached from the context. To attach it again, you simply need to do:

```
context.Attach(category);
```

However, you don't have direct access to your context here. This is yet one more reason that ***you should never use the repository pattern with EF***. So much pain and suffering has been subjected on developers throughout the year by either bad advice or erroneously attempting to do things as they are used to.

EF is an ORM (object relational mapper), which is a fancy way of saying that it is *itself* a data layer. The `DbContext` is the unit of work and each `DbSet` is a repository... already. The repository pattern is for abstracting *low-level* database access (i.e. all the crud of constructing SQL strings, for example). EF is already a high-level abstraction, trying to cram it into another repository pattern layer only cripples it and leads to problems like what you're experiencing here.

Long and short, the issue is that `category` is detached. You need to either ensure that it never becomes detached in the first place (i.e. don't use `AsNoTracking` for example) or find a way to ensure that it's reattached later. However, your best bet here is to throw away all this repository garbage completely and just use the context directly. Choosing to use an ORM like EF is simply choosing to use a third-party DAL, rather than write your own. Writing your own, anyways, on top of that is just wrong. You use the built in routing framework in ASP.NET Core. You use the built in templating engine (i.e. Razor). Do you feel the need to put some abstraction around those? Of course not, so why is a DAL any different? If you simply *must* create an abstraction, then use a meaningful one such as CQRS, service layer, or microservices patterns.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Alas, this is not my creation, I'm merely doing implementations on it and there's no way I can get rid of repositories. I'm not newing up a Category manually, I'm not using AsNoTracking or anything of the sort, it comes from the DbContext and hence it shouldn't be detached. There is some deeper rooted issue here, and this is why I included all the information that seemed relevant. Further tests showed that, even using `Include(category => category.User)` does not solve the problem. Rather, instead of throwing a duplicate key error on Category, it does so on AspNetUsers.

Comment: Oh, and I agree with you on your design observations, but again, I had nothing to do with the design or implementation of this, I just have to deal with it. If it were for me, I wouldn't touch EF with a ten foot pole and just use Dapper. It would mean a bit more work, but also way more control and the ability to easily make use of database-specific (PG, in this case) SQL capabilities, not to forget how easy it is to figure out what went wrong.